# Highcharts shows data but can't display chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to display dynamic highcharts which we can change the graph by Year, Month and Day.

I've made it successfully, i can change the X Axis based on each time and the data through Json array also passed successfully, however the chart doesn't come out.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'content/getChart.php',
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            type: type,
            part: part,
            year: year_val,
            month: month_val,
            day: day_val,
            days_in_month: days_in_month
        },
        success: function (data){
            var data_array = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                //data_array.push({x: val.time * 1000, y: val.value}); //first result
                data_array.push(val.time * 1000, val.value);
            });
            purchase_chart.series[0].setData(data_array);
            console.log(data_array);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
$purchase_array = array();
$array_test = array();
$resQry = "";
for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
    $resQry = "";
    $resQry .= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total_sum`";
    $resQry .= "FROM `purchase`";
    if($type == "daily" && $year != 0 && $month != 0 && $day != 0){
        $resQry .= "WHERE YEAR(`purchase_date`) = '$year' AND MONTH(`purchase_date`) = '$month' AND DAY(`purchase_date`) = '$i' ";
        $timemk = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year);
    }
    else if($type == "monthly" && $year != 0 && $month != 0){
        $resQry .= "WHERE YEAR(`purchase_date`) = '$year' AND MONTH(`purchase_date`) = '$i' ";
        $timemk = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 0, $year);
    }
    else if($type == "yearly" && $year != 0){
        $resQry .= "WHERE YEAR(`purchase_date`) = '$i' ";
        $timemk = mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $i);
    }
    $resQry .= "ORDER BY `purchase_date`";
    $result = $conn->query($resQry);
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $purchase_array[$timemk]['time'][] = $timemk;
    $purchase_array[$timemk]['value'][] = (int)$row['total_sum'];
}
$conn->close();
echo(json_encode($purchase_array));
```

I've tried many ways available, but only leads me as far as this.

The output:
[The one that i've circled has value of 12, if i hover on the X axis i can see the value shown 12 with it's correct date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9wTw.png)

Json output:

```
[{"x": 1385766000000,"y": [0]},
{"x": 1417302000000,"y": [0]},
{"x": 1448838000000,"y": [0]},
{"x": 1480460400000,"y": [12]},
{"x": 1511996400000,"y": [0]},
{"x": 1543532400000,"y": [0]},
{"x": 1575068400000,"y": [0}]
```

The result is still the same as the old code. However if i put the json array manually, it gives me highchart error #15.

and also, if i put the array like this (manually), the graph appears

```
[[1385766000000,0],
[1417302000000,0],
[1448838000000,0],
[1480460400000,12],
[1511996400000,0],
[1543532400000,0],
[1575068400000,0]]
```

Comment: What's the error was taken? Have you tried to check it via DOM (it could be a z-index issue)?

Comment: I would suggest to open console. Highchart in most cases push into it the error with a link of issue description, and possibilities to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `.setData(data_array);` to next line:

```
purchase_chart.series[0].setData([data_array], true);
```

It'll automatically trigger the chart's redraw action.

Also, next option might help:

```
// Front-End: change datetime to milliseconds
data_array.push([val.time * 1000, val.value]);

// Back-End [1]: submit time; remove convertation to string
$timemk = mktime(...);

// Back-End [2]: order dates; Highchart will stack when data is not ordered
$resQry .= "ORDER BY `purchase_date`";

// Back-End [3]: remove array bind for values
$purchase_array[$timemk] = array(
    'time' => $timemk,
    'value' => (int) $row['total_sum']
);
```

Comment: @ghost123, could you share your response from server?

Comment: Then, what's about the tiny change to align with your manual input (`data_array.push([val.time * 1000, val.value]);`)?

Comment: About that one more or less the result is: 
`1385766000000,[0],
 1417302000000,[0],
.....
]`

so the chart thinks the time and the value are two separated values so the graphic is like a sine wave (but yes at least the graphic shows)

i want to make it like:

`[1385766000000,0],
 [1417302000000,0],
.....
]`

Comment: Got it... remove array bind from PHP part

Comment: Sorry, array bind?

Comment: Whoa i'm following your lead, it solve my problem. Thanks a lot, how can i post the solution? Edit my own post?

Comment: You have a possibility to mark an answer as right (✓) near the left side. Good to hear, that you've resolved your issue.